# Extraction of the all tweets of particular user with timestamp

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to extract the all tweets and timestamp of particular person. I am new in python and tweepy. I have the working code from internet search, but my desire is to print only all tweets of particular user.

```
import tweepy
# Authentication details. To  obtain these visit dev.twitter.com
consumer_key = 'nWGEdfoaBt7d6wWhiAw5Tw'
consumer_secret = 'qM4QfDPqG9JQp6n0fqTCMrj6LJjES6vu2IzqpZLc'
access_token = '2284416938-JbD4F32m9xQPMxKoh6UikpCLoJm8F6xy8wDPS9P'
access_token_secret = 'XvJZQWa6zz5vHcHkUcYBacQKZJE9pcxbpxUUgNo9rN4AG'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create authentication token
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    print 'Getting statistics for @BarackObama:'

    # Get information about the user
    data = api.get_user('BarackObama')

    print 'Followers: ' + str(data.followers_count)
    print 'Tweets: ' + str(data.statuses_count)
    print 'Favouries: ' + str(data.favourites_count)
    print 'Friends: ' + str(data.friends_count)
    print 'Appears on ' + str(data.listed_count) + ' lists'
    print(data)
```

`print(data)` or `print(status)` only gives certain tweets(not all) along with  other unwanted information in JSON format.
     I found extracting only tweets from home and own timeline by use of following code

```
statuses = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items(2)
data = [s.text.encode('utf8') for s in statuses]
print data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I got the way to download tweet at single window by passing screenname or twitter id, it works for multiple user at a same time as well